# Difference in Prototype Inheritance, Firefox vs Chrome

Tags: javascript

For the following code:

```
function Mammal(){
    this.hair = true;
    this.backbone = true;
    return this;
}

function Canine(){
    this.sound= 'woof';
    return this;
}
Canine.prototype = new Mammal(); 

function Dog(name){
    this.tail=true;
    this.name=name;
    return this; 
}
Dog.prototype = new Canine();

var aspen = new Dog('Aspen');

var aspenProto = aspen.__proto__
```

Firebug (Firefox) wants to tell me `aspenProto` is `Mammal{}`, while Chrome is saying `Canine{}`.

Can anyone tell me why they display different, and if anyone else has ran into this issue?

Comment: I believe that's just a logging behavior. The behavior should be the same. Try checking with the `===` operator.

Comment: I don't know. They're both correct. It's up to the console developers to decide how data should be displayed.

Comment: I'm surprised by the Firebug behavior, since `Dog.prototype` _is_ a `Canine` (it also has `Mammal`ian properties, but it shouldn't matter)

Comment: Note that `IE` does not expose the `__proto__` property, so you shouldn't rely on it for general scripting.

Comment: @IHateLazy fixed. Note that a test in native Firefox should be done as well.

Comment: It's correct in actual JavaScript code. `aspen.__proto__ instanceof Canine; // true`

Comment: Native Firefox thinks it's Mammal as well.

Comment: This could be caused with Firefox' dead/static code optimisation. Try actually using the superclass.

Comment: Strange, `Dog.prototype.constructor` is `Mammal`, even in Chrome. Now to explain Chrome behavior.

Comment: @JanDvorak: They *are* `Mammal`. Why is this strange?

Comment: @IHateLazy I think I'm getting it. I just need the specification for `constructor`.

Comment: `Dog.prototype.constructor` is actually inherited, not `Canine`'s own.

Comment: @JanDvorak: It's because the default prototype objects are being overwritten, and the `.constructor` properties not replaced. The prototype chain will follow through until it finds a `.constructor`, which will be the first object that has not been overwritten, which is `Mammal`'s.

Comment: @IHateLazy I'm trying to find out why `Canine` instances don't have their own `constructor` property.

Comment: @JanDvorak: The instances themselves never do. It's always inherited from the prototype. It's the function's `.prototype` object that gets the automatic `.constructor` property. Trouble is that the function's `.prototype` objects are being destroyed, and replaced with new ones. The only default `.prototype` object that is not being destroyed is that of the `Mammal` function. *(And `Object.prototype` of course)*. If at the top we did `Mammal.prototype = {}`, then it's default object would be overwritten, and the next `.constructor` in line would be `Object.prototype.constructor`

Comment: @IHateLazy that's it. Will you write an answer?

Comment: @JanDvorak: I would, but it doesn't really answer the question of the different console outputs. That's merely a logging quirk as you correctly noted in your first comment. ...except I disagree that the behavior should be the same. There's no standard governing consoles, so there's nothing to say what should be logged.

Comment: @IHateLazy it's clear to me Firefox relies on `__proto__.constructor.name` while Chrome always uses the real constructor stored internally.

Comment: @JanDvorak: That makes sense. You post it and I'll +1 it. :)

Comment: Strange... Chrome console thinks `({constructor:function Hello(){}})` is a `Hello`.

Comment: @JanDvorak: The algorithm they use probably takes different paths in order to try to give something more meaningful than a plain `Object`. If they see that the actual constructor was `Object` *(or effectively so)*, then maybe they revert to the Firebug approach of looking for `constructor.name` in the chain. If you do this: `({constructor:{name:"Hello"}})` you also get `Hello` even though there's no function to be found.

Comment: @IHateLazy I'll do some testing with `new Object()` as well. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facts (credits go to @IHateLazy):

`aspenProto.constructor` is `Mammal`. This is because the `constructor` is actually an attribute of Mammal.prototype, set at the method creation time. `Canine.prototype.constructor`  is not `Canine`, since the prototype (holding the `constructor` property) was overwritten by `new Mammal()`.

Tests:

```
aspen.constructor = function Hello(){}; // aspen is Hello in Firebug,
                                        // Dog in Chrome
aspen.constructor.name = "test"         // still Hello in Firebug,
                                        // name is also Hello in both
aspen.constructor = function(){};       // aspen is Object in Firebug
aspen.constructor.name = "test"         // still Object in Firebug
aspen.constructor = null;               // still Object and Dog

({constructor: function Hello(){}})     // Hello in Firebug AND Chrome
({constructor: function (){}})          // Object in both (not surprisingly)
({constructor:{name:"Hi"}})             // "Object" in FB, "Hi" in Chrome

x={constructor:function(){})
x.constructor.name="Hello"              // x is Object in both

x=new Object()
x.constructor=function Hello(){}        // x is Hello in both

new (function(){})()                    // Object in both
new (function(){
  this.constructor=function Hello(){}
})()                                    // Hello in both
```

Conclusion:

Firebug always relies on the object's own `constructor` property to name it. If the `constructor` is a named function, it uses the `constructor` `name` (which is not writable - thanks @IHateLazy). If the `constructor` property is an anonymous function or not a function at all, then Firebug uses `"Object"` instead.

Chrome holds each object's actual constructor as an internal property. *Only* if that property is not accessible (the object was not constructed) or is Object, it looks at the object's `constructor` property. If the constructor is a named function, it uses its internally stored name. If the constructor is not a function or is anonymous it uses the `name` property.

Comment: +1 for a heck of a lot of digging and testing. You probably know this, but in browsers that support the *(non-standard)* `.name` property on functions, it's usually not writeable, so the `aspen.constructor.name = "test"` would have no effect. Trouble with console questions is that everything could change with the next release, so I usually avoid these. Glad you took care of it! ;-)

Comment: @IHateLazy You are right - it's not writable. Should have checked.

Comment: wow... How many edge cases will I find? I haven't checked if the Chrome's internal constructor property is visible across frames and windows.

Comment: I haven't tested in Firebug lite for Chrome yet.

Comment: Wow, thanks @JanDvorak and @I hate Lazy for your meticulous testing. If this were reddit, I've give you all the upvotes I could give.